# What causes the Pytorch nn Module to return a 1 or 0 for the argmax of this array?

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch

I have an array containing four random numbers that an argmax function should be returning a 0, 1, 2, or 3, but when the argmax is called from inside the nn.Module model it is always 0 or 1.
I would just like to know how and why it is always getting a 1 or 0 from the four numbers in the array.

Below I have the nn.Module and a comparison of a random array of len 3 computed inside and outside of the model using the function act (`Net.act`).

```
from torch import nn
import torch

import random


class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(4, 64),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(64, 2))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)

    def act(self, obs):
        obs_t = torch.as_tensor(obs, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
        q_values = self(obs_t.unsqueeze(0))
        max_q_index = torch.argmax(q_values, dim=1)[0]
        action = max_q_index.detach().item()

        return action


Net = Network()
```

This is a side by side comparison of a random array of len 3 inside and outside of the act function in the nn.Module (Net).

```
for _ in range(20):
    z = np.array([random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(4)])

    obs_t = torch.as_tensor(z, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
    q_values = (obs_t.unsqueeze(0))
    max_q_index = torch.argmax(q_values, dim=1)[0]
    action = max_q_index.detach().item()

    print(action, Net.act(z))
```

Output

```
3 0
0 0
2 0
0 0
2 0
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
0 1
0 0
1 1
3 1
3 0
1 0
0 1
3 0
3 0
0 0
1 0
```

Comment: `self.net`'s output layer has 2 entries (defined with `nn.Linear(64, 2)`) so an `argmax` can output only 0 or 1 there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self(obs_t.unsqueeze(0))` returns a 2 column matrix because the last layer of your model (`nn.Linear(64, 2)`) is defined to output two columns. `max_q_index` contains the column index of the largest value in each row of the model output (column index because `dim=1`). Since there are only 2 columns, `max_q_index` can only have values of 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your output to match change `q_values = self(obs_t.unsqueeze(0))`  to `q_values = obs_t.unsqueeze(0)` in `act` method
The reason being `self(obs_t.unsqueeze(0))` will actually call the method `forward` which has 2 output neuron Hence the output is either `0 or 1`.
Here is the output if i change `q_values = self(obs_t.unsqueeze(0))`  to `q_values = obs_t.unsqueeze(0)` in `act` method

```
1 1
1 1
3 3
0 0
2 2
2 2
1 1
0 0
1 1
3 3
3 3
1 1
3 3
3 3
3 3
0 0
3 3
1 1
1 1
2 2
```

Which you wanted